# Can we run cordova off jsfiddle or similar services?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jsfiddle

I am completely blank, and I am in a situation where I can't install the complete cordova toolset (node.js, git cli, etc), and even if I did my organization's internet policy doesn't allow these tools to work properly. But, I have to do some proof-of-concept apps using cordova.

I have not had a hands-on on apache cordova development so far. People say including cordova.js files in your html5 app does the trick. However, I need a hands-on on this.

Can we simply add cordova.js file into our page, write some logic that tries to access some native features (like camera), and, host it off jsfiddle, and then run those pages on our device browser? Will this work?!

I sadly don't see cordova.js files available on any CDN...

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding Cordova.js file doesn't help you achieve your needs, you must set up the Cordova project. First create the Cordova project and then build the project with which platform you want.

After that you can use [Cordova plugins](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/) to fulfill your needs. Actually, the Cordova.js file only acts as a JavaScript bridge to access the native features of the phone (camera, GPS, etc.).

If you want something more than that, Ionic framework is the best option in my opinion.

Comment: Are those plugins js files again?

Comment: Yes, but you don't add them manually if using CLI tools to install the plugins